# Consuming .NET Web Service with Dojo Javascript Library

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dojo

How do I consume a .NET Web Service using Dojo?  I believe I have the web service serializing its output as JSON but I'd like an example if anyone knows of one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.davebouwman.com/2008/09/19/posting-data-to-asp-net-json-services-with-dojo/

Answer (score 0):

The link in the answer has changed. It is now

http://blog.davebouwman.com/2008/09/19/posting-data-to-asp-net-json-services-with-dojo/